# Compact Two Functions in One View In Laravel

Tags: laravel, function, view, laravel-blade

In my Controller

```
public function startQ(Request $request){
       
        $users = question::limit(2)->get();
        return view('answerDesk',compact('users'));
       
}
public function answerQuestions(Request $request){
  
        $answers =$request->all();
        return view('answerDesk',compact('answers'));
}
```

in My View

```
 <form action="getAnswer" method="post" role="search"> @csrf @foreach($users as $answer) <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="{{$answer->id}}">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">
         <h4 style=""><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
             {{$answer->id}}:{{$answer->question}}
         </h4>
     </label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->a}}">(A) : <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{$answer->a}}</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->b}}">(B) : <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{$answer->b}}</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->c}}">(C) : <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{$answer->c}}</label><br>
     <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->d}}">(D) : <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1"> {{$answer->d}}</label><br>
     <input type="hidden" name="ans[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->ans}}"> @endforeach <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

I don't know how to use the `getAnswer` function

Can I Compact Two Functions in Controller To One View In Laravel?
If Yes How can I Do That?

Comment: What have you tried and what do you mean? `return view('dashboard');` in both controller functions? Show us what you mean.

Comment: actually i m making a quiz app and in my first function  i use an variable which can be used for foreach loop and in another function i make a query where the requested answer is stored and now i want to compare both answers the requested and the db answer if the requested answer match with the db answer i want to show the success note

Comment: And what isn't working for you? If you try each step, once you get stuck with an error we can help you.

Comment: i did'nt get any result on submission

Comment: Include the code that you have so we can help you. Right now to us, it is obvious you are not getting anything on submission because to us you have no code written.

Comment: check my code in edit

Comment: And what is your error?

Comment: don't know what to do next